# What are the main reasons to leave an IT Security position?

Tags: appsec, career

There are many questions here on [how to](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/programmer-to-security-professional/4666#4666) enter the field of IT Security. What are some reasons why people have left or are trying to get out of an IT Security position? This may be useful to know in figuring out whether this is a good career path.

Comment: Blackhats may be leaving to avoid being cemented into the nearest ocean or spending time in supermaxes...

Comment: @DeerHunter that's not really an IT Security position...I think he's talking about Security Officers, Penetration Testers, Identity Access managers, consultants,...

Comment: Sorry T.Webster - this is off topic, as the reasons are going to be the same as for leaving any job. You find something better, further along your career plan etc., or you leave to avoid someone/conditions

Answer (score 1):

Because they feel they have found something more interesting to do. Maybe they find developing something a lot more fun or they have shifter more towards management and they end up being in a broader position. For instance CSO to CIO.